# Is it possible to convert normal text to JSON format through python?

Tags: python, json

I have started getting good grips on python and at the same time I came across JSON article. From this, I thought to combine both concepts.
Currently I have a small script(python script) which fires some inbuilt commands and stores the output in a file.

Here's the code snippet

```
import subprocess, os

output_file_object = open("output.txt", "wb")       
command = ['/bin/ls', '-l']
command_output = subprocess.check_output(command)
output_file_object.write(command_output)
output_file_object.close()
print 'Done'
```

The file gets created and contains the output.

Is there any way where I can save this output in JSON format ? 
Is there any API or something ? 
What are the possible pre-requisites or steps that I will have to follow ??

Any suggestion will be highly appreciable .

Thanks,

Comment: There is a JSON module in the standard library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), but you have to parse the output from `ls` before creating a JSON file. If you want to parse using regexp, have a look at the `re` module.

Comment: What type of JSON representation are you expecting ?

Comment: @dilbert - I dint get you exactly ! Are there different representations for JSON ? Correct me pls, I am new to JSON here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am happy to answer my own question and I wish that this will help someone in need.

I used an API called Gelatin (https://github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/wiki). You will have to setup gelatin yourself as I am not explaining the setup process here.
At first it looked like a cumbersome task but the output that you get is really worth.  Internally gelatin uses json module of python.

For getting the perfect output, you will have to mesh around with the grammar of gelatin. In easy terms, I can say that "grammar" to gelatin is like "function" to any language.

"Grammar" is completely based on regular-expressions(regex). Yes! you will have to know a little bit about regex here. It will make the task of grammar definition easy.

> Lets get back to the solution of my question.

I had a text file which was the output of `ls` command.  The file contents are like this :

```
total 20 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 shiv shiv   0 Apr 25 10:42 output.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 shiv shiv 296 Apr 25 10:41 temp-script.py
```

Now lets start with defining the grammar.

You will have to define a new syntax file according to your needs.
Here's the syntax file that I made for "output command"

```
define nl /[\r\n]/
define ws /\s+/
define fieldname /[\w ]+/
define value /[^\r\n]+/
define field_end /[\r\n,] */
define colon_end /:/
define permission /[dl-][r-][w-][x-][r-][w-][x-][r-][w-][x-]/
define digit /[0-9]+/

grammar content:
    match permission ws value field_end:
        out.open('content')
        out.add_attribute('.', 'content-stuff', '$2')
        out.add_attribute('.', 'permission', '$0')
    match nl:
        do.return()
    do.return()

grammar input:
    match 'total' ws digit nl:
        out.open('tag1')
        content()
```

At the top are the regular-expressions which are, I guess, self explanatory
(IMPORTANT) - "grammar input" is the entry point. The gelatin parser will start execution from here. It is equivalent to "main" in C and C++.

Defining the syntax file was fun. You have to tell each and everything to the gelatin parser.

In "grammar input", I have told the parser to "match" something which starts with "total" followed by whitespace (ws) followed by "digit" and at last NewLine(nl). 
Once this match is found, it will open a json tag named "tag1" ( You can name it as per your convenience).

After opening the tag, next line was to call another grammar named "content" (this can also be any name)

Now "grammar content" which will find for line starting with "permission" which is nothing but the regex for permissions. 
Once the complete line is matched ie (permission ws value field_end), 
it will execute out.add_attribute function ('out' is an inbuilt object).

(NOTE- 'permission' is $0, 'ws' is $1, 'value' is $2 and so on..

```
out.add_attribute('.', 'content-stuff', '$2')
```

Remember we are in "tag1", 
    `'.' means current tag`
    `'content-stuff' -- Json "key"` 
    `'$2' -- JSON "value"`

out.open('content') - This is basically used when you want to create an array.

As the syntax is defined, its time to execute the command.

> gel -s <--syntax-filename.gel--> -f json <--input-filename-->
>
> gel -s syntax.gel -f json output.txt

```
{
    "tag1": {
        "content": [
            {
                "@content-stuff": "1 shiv shiv   0 Apr 25 10:42 output.txt", 
                "@permission": "-rw-rw-r--"
            }, 
            {
                "@content-stuff": "1 shiv shiv 296 Apr 25 10:41 temp-script.py", 
                "@permission": "-rw-r--r--"
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

This definitely took some time, but I want to share few silly (but hilarious) things that you seriously will have to take care while defining the syntax file or else you will go nuts.

`-Make sure there are no spaces left at the end of line(right hand side), especially while defining "grammar" (at the end after ':') [in syntax file]`

`-take care about using spaces and NO tabs. [in syntx file]` A TAB is equivalent to four SPACES, but you will have to manually give four SPACES, a single tab will lead to syntax error.

`-the "match" statement do not accepts spaces ie (as explained below)`

```
`-match 'Defines Permissions:' -->will NOT work`
`-match 'Defines' ws 'Permissions:' --> will WORK`
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have retrieved the output from the `ls` command :

```
>>> out = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

You just have to extract what you want, for example :

```
>>> # Get the lines, remove the first and the last ones, and split into columns
>>> out = [o.split() for o in out.split('\n')[1:-1]]
```

Then you just have to use json module :

```
>>> import json
>>> json_out = json.dumps(out)
>>> with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
>>>     f.write(json_out)
```

Obvisouly you have to do better than what I did here because splitting ls into columns does not output really readable JSON (You get tons of string, and the date is split into 3 parts).

Comment: This sounds interesting. I am giving this a shot right now.

Comment: I used this method. No doubt, it works, but with a small issue.
I get the output as one complete string. 

_"total 435 \n-rw-r--r-- 1 shiv shiv 1012 Apr 7 14:41 File.txt\n-rw-r--r-- shiv shiv ....<--stripped for brevity-->...."_

As you told, I will have to define the format first, isn't it ? 

And I have also heard about "Gelatin" [link](https://github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/wiki) 

I think this will also be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you have to define the output format you want. You can easily split the output by lines using `out.split('\n')` (see my post). In fact, once you'll have defined the format you want, you should create a kind of method `parseLine` and then do a `[parseLine(line) for line in out.split('\n')[1:-1]`. Then json.dumps() will take care of the conversion for you.